# Do we approve suggested edit robo?

Tags: discussion

This [user](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/25879/krishna-mohan) only doing [Suggested edit](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/25879/krishna-mohan?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) (only editing the title spelling mistake), Is this valid editing behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure quite what you mean; that user has contributed both questions and answers as well as edits.

I would say the usual advice applies: concentrate on the content of the edit rather than the person proposing it - if it's a good edit, accept it, if not, reject it.

Editing is an important part of the site; if a user feels they can help out more by cleaning up other questions/answers than they can by providing new content, I say let them at it, and a big thank you to them at the same time

Comment: only concern about the edit is, he is only editing the title spelling mistake and not sure to accept or reject ?

Comment: If you feel the edit is to minor, reject it as such :)

Comment: @Bala Titles should be impeccable.  Correcting spelling mistakes here is important, as it helps with search.  I will post more info about this when I get a chance.

Comment: @MPD I already approved many suggested edit from him and raised the question because of this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/27177 hope you understand.

Comment: @Bala I would have approved that.  I am searching for a particular post I remember to support the "titles should be impeccable" statement.  Having trouble finding it.

Comment: @MPD thanks for sharing your opinion and now I'm clear about this!

Answer (score 3):

I agree with MPD that titles are important, but I would rather prefer a suggested edit that changes most of the things that can be changed. For example, [this suggested edit](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/27177) doesn't touch the question text, which is the following.

> Have anyone measured the difference between preloading all changes in $node object and then do node_save () vs. injecting changes in node fields directly by doing db_insert ?

If you see the same user doing consecutive suggested edits like that, you could decline it. Once the declined suggested edits are higher than X, the user would not be allowed to suggest edits for 7 days.

Comment: And that's why I rejected some of his edits, and improved other ones... When I did much more in my improvement than he in original edit, I unchecked "helpful". I approved when I believed title was the only thing that needed changes.

Comment: And you are doing well. That is what I would do too.

Comment: @Mołot - My intention was, corrected spelling mistakes helps with search.Thanks for giving clear idea on this.I'll be cautious

Comment: @kiamlaluno - Thanks, I'll be cautious.I thought that the 'title' plays major role in search. (even though the title text doesn't touch the question text).
How can a user know his rejected edits?

Comment: @KrishnaMohan you can check your suggested edits here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/25879/krishna-mohan?tab=activity

Comment: @Bala - Thanks bala,it shows all of my suggested edits.how could I know my rejected edits? If every user know his rejected edits, that helps to improve his editing behaviour.

Comment: @KrishnaMohan click the suggested edit link in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/25879/krishna-mohan?tab=activity